# How can I call a callback in a Rhino Mock'd object?

Tags: c#, rhino-mocks

I know there has to be a way to do this...I'm just new to RhinoMocking.

Essentially, I have the following class:

```
class B
{
     private object _dependency;

     public B(object dependency)
     {
          _dependency = dependency;
     }

     public void Method()
     {
         dependency.DependencyMethod(delegate(){ Method2(); });
     }

     private void Method2()
     {
         // do stuff
     }
}
```

I'm passing a rhino mocked, interface as a dependency in my test.  I want to test Method2 in my test...but its private, so the only way to get at it is by looking at the argument to DependencyMethod.  How do I do that? :P

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to test a private method?  Usually, you don't test private methods -- just the public interface.

Comment: I normally agree...however in actually (aka...the non abstracted version of this problem), private Method2 is a async callback; that is getting set in a public method; and then called later.  In order to fully test my scenario; I need to call it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after digging around, I think the best way to do this is to use GetArgumentsForCallsMadeOn on my mock, to grab the delegate that way and then call it.

Answer (score 0):

One test should determine that Method() passes a delegate.
Another test should determine that the real dependency calls the delegate.

To to verify that Method() passes the delegate to Method2 you need to make the delegate visible. Perhaps you can pass this as a dependency so that in another test you can verify that Method() passes you the delegate that you passed in.

```
 private object _dependency;
 private delegate_type _delegate;

 public B(object dependency, delegate_type theDelegate)
 {
      _dependency = dependency;
      _delegate= theDelegate;
 }

 public B(object dependency) : this(dependency, delegate(){ Method2(); }) {}

 public void Method()
 {
     dependency.DependencyMethod(theDelegate);
 }
```